# Trailing data дата при сохранении даты

Tags: php, laravel5, carbon

Всем привет,
В laravel 5.5 проекте обновляется строка кодом

```
$inputsArray = $request->all();
echo '<pre>$inputsArray::'.print_r($inputsArray,true).'</pre>';
$tmpCsvp->update($inputsArray);
```

И получаю ошибку

```
Trailing data
```

В массиве inputsArray есть поле

```
[date_loan_closing] => '2017-11-30'
```

которое в таблице postgres определено как date и в миграции определено:

```
$table->date('date_loan_closing');
```

Подебажив я в методе createFromFormat(файл vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php)
вижу что дата была передана как

```
$time = 2017-11-08 00:00:00
```

Не пойму откуда взялиcь нули по вызову метода update и как с ними бороться?

В модели есть метод

```
public function getDateLoanClosingAttribute($date) : string
{
    if ( empty($date) ) return '';
    return $this->getFormattedDate($date);
}
```

Но он не помогает...

Спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения атрибута:

```
   public function setDateLoanAttribute($value)
   {
       $this->attributes['date_loan'] = $value;
   }
```